# VBA - Creating a dynamic table and proportionally spreading values out based on variable term

Tags: excel, vba

I'm quite new to VBA and have been doing some searching but have yet to find what I need.

I have some data in a table that includes Id field, Commission amount, start date and contract term.

From this data I need to create another table that in the first column has the IDs and after that creates a column header for each month (start (B1) and end months (B2) worked out from the data) and splits the commission equally over the term period.

The code I have for working out the column headers is below, but it doesn't help with the rest.

```
Sub tableFill()
  Dim d1 As Date, d2 As Date, Tbl As Range
  d1 = Range("B1").Value
  d2 = Range("B2").Value
  Set Tbl = Range("J6:BV6")
  Call setLabels(d1, d2, Tbl)
End Sub

Sub setLabels(dt1 As Date, dt2 As Date, rng As Range)
    Dim rToFill As Range, r As Range
    Set rToFill = Intersect(rng(1).EntireRow, rng).Offset(0, 0)
    For Each r In rToFill
        dv = DateSerial(Year(dt1), Month(dt1) + i, Day(dt1))
        r.Value = dv
        i = i + 1
        If dt1 + i > dt2 Then Exit Sub
    Next r
End Sub
```

Any help appreciated. Thanks

Comment: *"The code I have for working out the column headers is below, but it doesn't help with the rest."* - Not really sure what you mean by this, what is the exact problem you're running into?

Comment: Sorry If I've been unclear, I actually have this working as a formula, (=IF(AND(J$6>=INDEX('Raw Data'!$K$2:$K$8,MATCH(Table!$C7,'Raw Data'!$D$2:$D$8,0)),J$6<=INDEX('Raw Data'!$L$2:$L$8,MATCH(Table!$C7,'Raw Data'!$D$2:$D$8,0))),INDEX('Raw Data'!$J$2:$J$8,MATCH(Table!$C7,'Raw Data'!$D$2:$D$8,0),1),"")) however 
a. it's a bit cumbersome and 
b. I would like to run a for loop to check this formula in each of the cells (rather than having the formula in each cell) does this make sense?